# Clarification on ie detection with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I was looking up ways to detect ie browsers in javascript, and this was one of the solutions I found:

```
if (-[1,]) {
    //Not IE

} else {
    //IE
}
```

This works, and I can apply CSS using this just fine. What my question is, is what is going on behind the scenes here? I do not understand this conditional and typing it into google gets me interesting, but not relevant results...

### EDIT

My code is working fine. I have tested it in all browsers and all versions of IE. At this point it is merely a curiosity why this is working. It looks like it has something to do with arrays and negative index or something like. That is my question, **WHY**, not how do I get it to work because it already works.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use condtional comments, or, better yet, feature detection.

Comment: IE9 will fail the check if you want all IE's

Comment: Or conditional compilation if you want to target IE10 too

Comment: Jeff, That code will not detect all versions of IE like your "Edit" seems to claim. Hit F12 and look at what Browser/Document Mode the IE browser is running in. It is probably running in IE8 mode.

Comment: @epascarello I am applying CSS3 styles inside the conditional and ie9 has the ability to do that. It is good ie9 passes this test.

Comment: @SLaks Technically, isn't this the same as feature detection?

Comment: @jefffabiny: Emphatically not, unless you **only** care about that particular bug.  The whole point of feature detection is to not assume that browsers with bug / missing feature X also have bug / missing feature Y.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, that would be the situation. I do not have separate stylesheets; just the one CSS3 (background-size) that needs to work in ie7/8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE has a Javascript parsing issue: `[1,]` is parsed as `[1, undefined]`.
Conforming browsers ignore the comma and parse it as `[1]`

The unary negation operator, when applied to an array of length one, will negate the array's single element.
Therefore, `-[1]` is `-1` (which is truthy).
However, `-[1, anything]` (which is how IE parses `[1,]`) is `NaN`, which is falsy.

However, **you should not rely on this behavior**.

Instead, use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which will automatically add classes for each **feature**, regardless of browser.
If you really want to differentiate IE specifically (which is a bad idea), use [conditional comments](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

Answer (score 4):

Open up the console and see what is happening.

Chrome:

```
> -[1,]
  -1
> [1,].length
  1
```

IE 8

```
> -[1,]
  NaN 
> [1,].length
  2
```

IE 9

```
> -[1,]
  -1
> [1,].length
  1
```

---

IE8 will go into the else statement since `NaN` is a *falsely* value. `-1` is a *truthy* value so it will be treated as true. It is basically testing how the browser treats the trailing comma in an array. IE8 and under adds an extra index while the others ignore the comma. IE9+ fixed that and also ignore it. The magic works when the Unary Minus [a Unary plus could have been used] converts the array to a number and you get the `NaN` or `-1` depending the array having the extra undefined index.

If your code is going into the else on IE9 or IE10, than that means your page is not running in IE9/10 mode but in IE8 or IE7 mode.

Comment: But it shows what is going on, which it seems like the OP had no clue how to debug in the first place.